# Unity 3d and blender horror game developing

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, blender

I`m trying to develope a horror game in blender and unity3d. The whole game will be in a house. I just wanna ask, where I should build that house in Unity or Blender? And where I have to texture it? Btw: I will maybe want to move some walls. Thank you.

Comment: Build Models in Blender. Position them in Unity. You could make a house with objects in Unity but it gives you less control over how it would look. Textures can take the form of image files wrapped over the models. Google UV Maps for tutorials on how to do this.

Comment: create walls, pillars, doors, floors, windows, beams, ceilings, stairs, furniture, and whatnot (especially a lot of props like lamps, plates, pots, radiators, pipes, vents, ...) in blender, then put it all together in unity and try to reuse items as much as possible without making it appear repetitive. also, to save up on draw calls remember more materials equals more draw calls. so maybe consider using texture atlases. aside of that, this is not the correct place for this question, stack overflow is about programming problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a programmer not a modeler so I am no expert in this subject, but I would personally use one or the other depending on the style of my game assets. If my game assets were very simple and kind of cubic like in [Minecraft](https://minecraft.net/en/) or [Unturned](http://store.steampowered.com/app/304930/?l=english), then I would use Unity to create my assets. Otherwise if I wanted my assets to be more complex and detailed I would use blender.